# I recently asked two questions specific to DVD releases; do they belong here or in another group?

Tags: discussion, scope

I recently asked [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/10304/has-the-mighty-orbots-cartoon-series-ever-been-released-on-dvd-and-why-not) and [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/10305/why-were-2-episodes-left-off-of-the-the-tick-dvd-releases-and-why-was-season), both related to DVD releases of cartoon robots and cartoon super-heroes respectively.

Is **Movies and TV** the appropriate place to ask about them, or is [Sci Fi and Fantasy](http://scifi.stackexchange.com) more appropriate, or even [Anime & Manga](http://anime.stackexchange.com) (considering the robot show)?

Do note that I did not cross-post the questions I asked, but I did ask a variation of **this** question on the Sci-Fi meta.

Comment: youmay get more focused answers  there, but it is not out of our scope in the slightest

Comment: FYI The Mighty Orbots question is probably on topic on [Anime & Manga](http://anime.stackexchange.com/). We'd classify it as anime because it's made by a Japanese studio and inspired by a number of other anime, so it's well within our scope. However, we haven't dealt with questions about the availability of U.S. releases of anime, and in my opinion that's not really our area of expertise. Still, you're more than welcome to ask other questions there (just don't post the same question on multiple sites). The worst that will happen is that we migrate it here or somewhere else where it fits.

Comment: Anime question are all allowed on M&Tv and SciFi question too till its in a QA format but Cross-posting them is discouraged. You can ask them where you want them to ask till they are in the region of On-topic.

Comment: Related: [Are questions about DVD's of movie/TV-shows on-topic?](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1442/1876)